# How to get current user address from firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

How do I get the current user address from firebase? Need help for this part. I have used current user's to call the address, but can't get it.
I am able to get all the user address from the firebase. But when I tried below to retrieve the current user address it failed.

```
 openMapPage()
  {


    var ref = firebase.database().ref("request");
    ref.once("value").then((snapshot) => { // <------ Here!
        var a = snapshot.exists();  // true
        var c = snapshot.hasChild("reqdetails"); // true
        var d = snapshot.child('reqdetails').exists();
        var requestsKey = snapshot.key;
        var requestsValue = snapshot.val();


        //var currentadd = requestsKey.reqdetails.address;


          //this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(data =>{
      ///this.profileData = this.af.object(this.user);
            //console.log(this.profileData);
    //}) 

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
         var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
         var currentUserId = user.uid;

         var currentadd = this.currentUserId.regdetails.address;
          console.log("Current User Address");
          console.log(currentadd);

        } else {
    // No user is signed in.
        }
      });



        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => { // <------ And here!
            var requestKey = childSnapshot.key;
            var requestValue = childSnapshot.val();
            var reqdetails = requestValue.reqdetails;
            var AllUserAddress = requestValue.regdetails.address;


           //var currentUserAdd = currentUserId.address;




            if (reqdetails) {
                this.data = requestKey;
                console.log(this.data);
                //this.arr.push(requestKey);
                //console.log(this.arr);

                 this.getRequest = this.angFire.list('request', {
                   query: {
                   orderByChild: 'reqdetails',
                   startAt: 'reqdetails'
            }
         }) 


            }
        });

    });     
  }
```

My constructor where i declare currentUserId.

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private angFire: AngularFireDatabase,private af: AngularFireDatabase,
  private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    //this.request = angFire.list('/request');

    this.getRequest = angFire.list('request', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'reqdetails',
        startAt: 'reqdetails'
      }
    })

        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        var currentUserId = user.uid;

    //this.userreq = angFire.list(`${this.userkey}`);
    //this.reqdetails = angFire.list('reqdetails');
    //this.request = angFire.list(this.data);

  }
```

This is how my firebase console look like
[image]

Now i am gettting this error

[image]

Comment: Ok reqdetails and regdetails has address. But i can't get address from the current user

Comment: Have you tried to console.log(childsnapshot.val()) to ensure that you're receiving a value to begin with?

I can't see any issues with how you're getting the address from the snapshot, assuming  that the value of childsnapshot is the '0AJ2wNW...' node in the screen capture you provided.

Comment: Yup. I can't understand why I can't get the current user address though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer makes these assumptions:

- you have a user logged in
- the key of your request record is the uid of the user who is currently logged in

Your problem is that when you create the database reference:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("request");
```

You are not targeting the child node of `request` using the current user's uid. You need to get the current user's uid and then create the database reference this way:

```
var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
var ref = firebase.database().ref("request/" + uid);
```

You seem to be thinking that there is a connection between the authentication data in firebase and the realtime database. There is no connection between these two things in Firebase - you can only use the user's uid to link data in the realtime database to a user.

Here are two possibilities using the Firebase SDK and AngularFire2 for your `openMapPage()` function:

**1) Firebase SDK:**

```
var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid; // Gets current user uid as string
var ref = firebase.database().ref('request/' + uid); // Make database ref which points to a child node of request that matches the current user's uid
ref.once('value', (request) => {
    var currentUserAddress = request.val().reqdetails.address;
  });
```

**2) AngularFire2:**

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
var auth$ = this.afAuth.authState; // Get an observable of the authstate for the current user

var userRequest$ = auth$.switchMap((auth: firebase.User) => { // Use switchMap to subscribe and get the authstate
    return this.af.object('request/' + auth.uid); // Use the uid to get the appropriate "request" node
});

userRequest$.subscribe((request) => { // subscribe to the userRequest$ observable (I would suggest returning this to your component and using the async pipe instead of subscribing here)
  var currentAdd = request.reqdetails.address; // access the address
});
```

Comment: I tried to follow the link you gave me. Now it's giving me an undefined currentUserId error. I have updated my post

Comment: It&#39;s returning undefined because the currentid is only a string value of the current user&#39;s uid. The currentid variable is not an object from the database, it is a string from the firebase.auth(). currentuser

I'll change my answer and fill this out some more when I'm in front of my PC later today

Comment: Thank you very well explained

Comment: please could you help look at this too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65672383/how-to-query-each-users-submission-from-firebase-realtime-database-with-angular