# How do you query and display the authenticated user's order from the Firebase Realtime Database using AngularFire in an Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the function I am using to insert orders into the database, which works fine.

```
async createPackage(){
const itemsRef = this.afDatabase.database.ref(`delivery orders/${this.uid}`);
const userId = 
itemsRef.push({packageName: this.packageName, packageSize: this.packageSize, packageDescription: this.packageDescription, packageFrom: this.packageFrom, packageTo: this.packageTo, deliveryDate: this.deliveryDate, receiverNumber: this.receiverNumber, paymentOption: this.paymentOption, UID: this.uid})

this.packageName = '';
this.packageDescription = '';
this.packageFrom = '';
this.packageTo = '';
this.deliveryDate = '';
this.paymentOption = '';
this.receiverNumber = '';
this.packageSize = '';

this.showAlert('Your package delivery order has been successfully taken.', 'You will be contacted by one of our Administrators soon.');
```

}

here is a screenshot of how it's been structured in the database, the parent node is the user uid for each user, while the child node is the id for each order by each user.
[image: database screenshot]

the problem I am having is how to query and display each user's order separately on their dashboard differently on the front end.

Comment: When you run this code in a debugger, what specific line in the code you shared isn't doing what you expect it to do?

Comment: what i need help with is how i'm going to write a query to get each user's delivery orders. Presently i have two test users and i've made two orders each with both account with their uid as the parent node/key and each order IDs goes under each user's uid.

Comment: Can you update the question to include what you’ve tried to do to query this - a good start would be a function where you get the currently authenticated user’s userId (you can use the answer of mine that you commented on to get the userId - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45481981/6288171) and create a reference to the RTDB using the userId. Happy to look and write an answer but need a bit more context.

Comment: okay @nclarx, 'm happy to hear from you, i succeeded in getting each user's entry when i console logged them. i'll be sharing the code while i update the question. so the only problem i'm having now is displaying them on my angular frontend. Thanks

Comment: @nclarx the bit of code i just added as the answer gives me each user's order post on the console just as i've console logged it. so please can you help me with displaying them on the frontend with Angular.

Answer (score 1):

For context, the complete files for this answer can be found here: https://gist.github.com/nclarx/ef581b0e1a95a2d43531411fe91a9814

### To Query the User's Orders

To query the user's data you need to use a function similar to the following:

```js
getCurrentOrder(): Observable<Order[] | never> { 
    return this.afAuth.authState // authState is an observable
      .pipe( // use pipe
        switchMap((user) => { // switchMap gets authState and then lets you return a different observable
          // The following returns an observable call to the real-time database:
          return user ? this.afDatabase.list<Order>(`delivery-orders/${user.uid}`).valueChanges() // if the user is authenticated an observable with the Orders is returned
                      : EMPTY; // if the user is not authenticated an empty observable is returned
        })
      );
  }
```

This isn't an ideal way to do authentication in a larger application. I suggest you look at this video on Authentication with AngularFire https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qP5zw7fjQgo and https://fireship.io/lessons/angularfire-google-oauth/ to create an `AuthService` that can be used across your application.

### Displaying the Orders

To display that information in an Angular component using Observables from AngularFire I suggest the following structure/pattern:

- `OrderService` - contains methods for accessing the database (generate the service with the Angular CLI)
- `AppComponent` - has `OrderService` injected and calls `getCurrentUserOrder()` when the component initialises `ngOnInit()`
- Template: `app.component.html` - the template which uses the `async` pipe in a `*ngFor` directive to subscribe/unsubscribe to the observable automatically.

Handing an observable to the template and using the `async` pipe to subscribe to it is good practice because it means that you do not need to subscribe and unsubscribe from an observable manually.

The files can be found in their entirety here: https://gist.github.com/nclarx/ef581b0e1a95a2d43531411fe91a9814

See the comments in the code for important points about how this works.

#### The Service: `OrderService.ts`

```js
import {Injectable}        from '@angular/core';
import {EMPTY, Observable} from 'rxjs';

import {AngularFireAuth}     from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {switchMap}           from 'rxjs/operators';
import {AngularFireDatabase} from '@angular/fire/database';

export interface Order {
  // write interfaces for all of your objects and use them
  // when defining variables and function return types.
  packageName: string;
  packageSize: number;
  packageDescription: string;
  packageFrom: string;
  packageTo: string;
  deliveryDate: Date;
  receiverNumber: number;
  paymentOption: string;
  UID: string;
}

export class OrderService {

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase) {
  }

  getCurrentOrder(): Observable<Order[] | never> { // note the use of the interface: Order[], which means returning an array of Orders
    return this.afAuth.authState // authState is an observable
      .pipe( // use pipe
        switchMap((user) => { // switchMap gets authState and then lets you return a different observable
          // The following returns an observable call to the real-time database:
          return user ? this.afDatabase.list<Order>(`delivery-orders/${user.uid}`).valueChanges() // if the user is authenticated an observable with the Orders is returned
                      : EMPTY; // if the user is not authenticated an empty observable is returned
          // NOTE: this observable is not called until it is subscribed to in the template using the `async pipe`, see
          // `app.component.html` where it has `*ngFor="let order of orders$ | async"` <== this is what kicks off the request to the database
        })
      );
  }
}
```

#### The Component: `app.component.ts`

```js
import {Component, OnInit}   from '@angular/core';
import {Order, OrderService} from './order.service';
import {Observable}          from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'ng-fire-so-qtn';

  orders$: Observable<Order[]>; // property to hold the observable which will have your array of Orders

  constructor(public orderService: OrderService) { // inject the OrderService into the component
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.orders$ = this.orderService.getCurrentOrder();
    // When this component is initialised it will set the `orders$` property to the `Observable<Order[]>` so it is available in the template
  }
}
```

#### The Template: `app.component.html`

```html
<section>
  <ul *ngIf="orders$ | async"> <!-- The *ngIf will hide the whole list until the data has arrived-->
    <li *ngFor="let order of orders$ | async"> <!-- The *ngFor will loop over and create list items for the orders once the data has arrived-->
      {{order.packageName}}: {{order.packageDescription}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: tried this just now and it didn't work, it's not displaying anything on the frontend. @nclarx

Comment: can you put your example in a Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/, you don't need to connect it to your actual database, would just be easier to see issues with your code

Comment: can you also check the console for error messages - telling me it didn't work doesn't give me any indication of what is wrong - try to include error output

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-grsf8h?file=src/app/order.service.ts this is a stackblitz I made, it does not include the code for AngularFire in the `OrderService` but it works correctly returning an observable with an `Order[]` from the service to the component, which is then rendered in the template.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it. Can you mark my answer as the accepted if it was the solution. Cheers

Comment: @AWESOMEWORLD ^^

Comment: … not sure what happened here @AWESOMEWORLD ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, i finally was able to query each user's submission from the firebase realtime database with angular with this few lines of code.

```
getCurrentUserOrder() {
 return this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
    if(user) {
      this.userId = user.uid;
   console.log(user.uid)
   console.log(user.email)
 }
 this.afDatabase.list(`delivery orders/${this.userId}`).valueChanges().subscribe(
   data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.orders = data;
   }
 );
 
 
});
```

after importing the AngularFireDatabase and the AngularFireAuth inside the component.On the frontend,

```
<section *ngFor="let order of orders">
    <ion-card>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="cube" slot="end"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>{{order.packageName}}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    
      <ion-card-content>
        
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
  </section>
```

this solves the entire problems completely.

Comment: @nclarx this is the code. Can you please help out?

Comment: See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65716175/6288171